# SPCalendarView control, same events are displayed each month in a VisualWebPart UserControl.ascx.cs file

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, user-controls, visual-web-part

I am creating a custom SharePoint Calendar to pull from multiple SharePoint Calendar Lists.

In the markup I have the following:

```
<SharePoint:SPCalendarView ID="EventsCalendar2" width="100%" runat="server"></SharePoint:SPCalendarView>
```

I bind it like this in page load after getting the site and list `myItems` is a `SPListItemCollection`:

```
EventsCalendar2.DataSource = MakeSchedule(myItems);
EventsCalendar2.DataBind();
```

The `MakeSchedule(myItems)` is the following:

```
private SPCalendarItemCollection MakeSchedule(SPListItemCollection myItems)
        {
            SPCalendarItemCollection items = new SPCalendarItemCollection(); 

            for (int i = 0; i < myItems.Count; i++)
            {
                SPListItem item = myItems[i];

                DateTime StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(item["EventDate"]);
                DateTime EndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(item["EndDate"]);

                string Description = "";
                if (item["Description"] != null)
                    Description = item["Description"].ToString();

                string Location = "";
                if (item["Location"] != null)
                    Location = item["Location"].ToString(); 

                bool Recurrance = false;
                if (item["fRecurrence"] != null)
                    Recurrance = (bool)item["fRecurrence"];

                bool AllDayEvent = false;
                if (item["fAllDayEvent"] != null)
                    AllDayEvent = (bool)item["fAllDayEvent"];



                items.Add(
                    new SPCalendarItem()
                    {
                        ItemID = item["ID"].ToString(),
                        StartDate = StartTime,
                        EndDate = EndTime,
                        hasEndDate = true,
                        Title = item["Title"].ToString(),
                        Location = Location,
                        Description = Description,
                        IsAllDayEvent = AllDayEvent,
                        IsRecurrence = Recurrance,
                        CalendarType = (int)SPCalendarType.Gregorian
                    }


                    );
            }

            return items; 
        }
```

NOW **I can't figure out why the events are being displayed in all of the months when they should only be displayed in the months specified by `StartDate` & `EndDate`.** Any ideas on what I am doing wrong??

**Could it be that the `SPCalendarView` control cannot be used in a VisualWebPart?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to set the `SPCalendarView`'s `V4Rendering` property to `false` to get it working (`EnableV4Rendering="false"`). Of course this isn't the best solution as this removes some functionality added onto the Calendar from SharePoint 2007.

Other things I have come across in my research was that this is definitely a `VisualWebPart` issue in particular the UserControl. I will edit this answer with the link.

A solution offered by others is updating the SharePoint server with the December2011 cumulative update. I will try that tomorrow, but for now that is the temporary solution.

http://www.sharepointdevelopment.me/2012/03/harnessing-the-spcalendarview/

&& Yes the HotFix I applied fixed it, here is the link:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2596998

Answer (score 2):

for starters, you are calculating start and end dates differently

```
  DateTime StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(item["EventDate"]);
  DateTime EndTime   = Convert.ToDateTime(item["EndDate"]  ).Date;
```

You should also use `Convert.ToBoolean()` rather than casting it as `x = (bool) object`.  I've seen the latter fail in strange ways and if that happens to be the case here, then you could be ending up with `Recurrance` being true when it shouldn't be.

Comment: sorry I should have cleared my code before i pasted it here. What you have indicated is what I started off with I added .Date extension to both StartTime and EndTime and forgot to delete .date when I pasted the code here and I also had Convert.ToBoolean() initially and saw examples that use (bool) so I thought I'd try it that way.. but the problem persists through all of those scenarios lol I initially thought it was which cast type i used and date part i used too!!

Comment: When you click on subsequent months in the calendar, does the first of the month change as it should or is it simply showing the same calendar after each click?

Comment: Same calendar after each click

Comment: except the month is different

Comment: Blast... I just reread this whole post.  I bet the root of the problem is that your `DataBind()` is in _load and is probably firing every time the page posts back, which resets all internal calendar data every page load.  Try wrapping your `DataBind()` command in a `if (!Page.IsPostBack) {}` block

Comment: I tried that as well my friend, and it removes it from the month it should be in as well =[ I don't know I'm beginning to think it is because this code is in the UserControl.ascx.cs... and that maybe this issue is there because im using a VisualWebPart not a standard WebPart

Comment: Can you try this?  Add the logic in there so the DataBind is only executed on !Page.IsPostBack, close your browser, reopen it and navigate to the page rather than merely refreshing it.  Does it behave the same?

Comment: Yeah, it does. with the `!Page.IsPostBack` around the `DataSource` and `DataBind()` it appears when i am first at the month the event should be rendered in (i.e. `Page_Load`) but when I want to go back to the month after I click through to the next, the event disappears .. which I think is reasonable since we're going back to the same month through a `PostBack` o and I also tried the `!IsPostBack` with `EnableViewState = "true"` too... but that did absolutely nothing

Comment: Ok I really think it is a `UserControl` thing I'm going to edit the question